# Register Page instantly buffering

Tags: django

When I tried to register in my site, it's instantly buffering,

[image]

The server is working properly and others were coded finely.

The `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Login Page
    url(r"^login/$", login, {'template_name':'users/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    #Logout Page
    url(r"^logout/$", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    # Registration Page
    url(r"^register/$", views.register, name='register'),
]
```

The `views.py`

```
def register(request):
    """Register a new user."""
    if request.method != "POST":
        #display blank register form.
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        # process completed form.
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            # Log the user in and then redirect to home page
            authenticate_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username,
                password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, authenticate_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:index'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

Double checked I am in the right views.py

The register.html is:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <form  action="{% url "users:register" %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button name="submit">log in</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url "learning_logs:index" %}">

    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Where might be the problem live?

Comment: wierd. what's your http response in runserver shell?

Comment: also please upload your `UserCreationForm` and `register.html` (only form part)

Comment: You link should be `http:/127.0.0.1:8000/register/` as per your `urls.py`, are you looking at the right view?

Comment: `[24/May/2018 08:34:56] "GET /users/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2893
Performing system checks...` @seuling

Comment: wierd for `performing system checks`. No problem (with that message) from other views ? (like login, logout)

Comment: It works when re-open the chrome .

Comment: Could you please collect your comments to the answer. @seuling